# C++ IDE with special features

Tags: windows, software-development, c++, ide

I'm new to C++ and started using Visual Studio Express 2013 because it is often named as "the best" C/C++ IDE.

However as someone used to Java and Eclipse I do not like Visual Studio very much.
Here are some features that it's lacking (afaik) and that I want to have. They are listet descending in order of importance.

- Code synchronization between header and cpp files. (When I define a function in a .cpp file the function header should appear in the .h with just one click. And vice versa)
- Creation of function by calling (Like Eclipse,  When I call methodXY from Object XY somewhere but the function is not yet declared it should give me the option to automatically create the function.)
- Indication of errors in files without the need to select them. (Like Eclipse, when I have 3 files open it should indicate which are with errors in the Tab and Tree view of the Project)
- Automatic generation of get and set Methods

Can you name my a C++ IDE for Windows that supports such features?

Comment: First, you should be using the Community Edition of Visual Studio.  There's no restrictions with that version.  Second, Visual Studio has several add ons.  Have you checked to see if any give you the features you want?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using eclipse then if it has the features you want?  As you can use eclipse with the Microsoft compiler amongst others.

Comment: I am currently Festung eclipse cdt. I luke ue A Kot But Code completion for c++ is Not as good as with Java or visual studio

Comment: I'm not a C++ developer, but I use JetBrains' IDEs. All of them are based on the IntelliJ IDEA, which is considered a top Java IDE, and they include almost any integration I could think of. The company have just released [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/), a new C/C++ IDE. I advice you to take a look at it.

Comment: @Nadav S. Do you find cmake convenient on Windows ? I love JetBrains and all their IDE however, trying to link libraries on Windows with CLion was very hard and painful. I ended up using QtCreator just because of that.

Comment: So did you find what you were looking for ? Which IDE are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try [Code Lite](http://codelite.org/). It has e.g. automatic setters and getters. You can also write function implementations with a click. It indicates errors by giving the name of the file (without the need to select it).

Comment: Does it have suport for creating GUI?